# “Stock pole” vs. “pole stock”

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-order

I found this sentence, and it confused me:

> Loads may be transferred in one operation from **stock pole**, production point or delivery vehicle practically to their destination on the building.

I looked it up through Google, where what I found most is *pole stock*. I know *pole stock* means lumber used in making poles for vehicles and agricultural implements.  But what does *stock pole* mean?

Comment: Apparently, *stock pole* is the location where *pole stock* may be stocked. That could be a shortening of *stock of poles*.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered the possibility that there is a typographical error in your source? I would expect to find loads being transferred from a **stock pile** to their destination.

Comment: Good comment.  Not an answer (unless you have access to the original source and can show that this explanation makes sense in context).

Answer (score 0):

I do have a similar sentence using stock pole:
The outer shell can be mounted to existing street furniture or stock poles, greatly reducing purchase and transportation cost.

This sentence here would suggest metal poles used for fences for stock...

Comment: Welcome! Give a source for that sentence, and the answer will be much better.